# How to modify a text file by grabbing a portion of text from text another file?

Tags: regex

There's a text file named main.txt.
I want to modify it by grabbing some part of text from grab.txt to have the desired output.

cat main.txt

```
X9tTDHSc-32313922.mp4-X9tTDHSc-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 1 -
6auM6kSh-32313922.mp4-6auM6kSh-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 2 -
F3LUhgbw-32313922.mp4-F3LUhgbw-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 3 -
F3LUhvvv-32313999.mp4-F3LUhvvv-32313999.mp4.mp4 Lecture 19 -
NTyKAqNx-32313922.mp4-NTyKAqNx-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 4 -
RJUSaTnb-32313922.mp4-RJUSaTnb-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 5 -
```

cat grab.txt

```
Definition Lecture 1
Objectives of Auditing Lecture 2
Scope of Auditing Lecture 3
Just a test for it to work randomly Lecture 19
Types of Audit Lecture 4
Inherent Limitations Lecture 5
```

Added random number because numbers will not always be in sequence

**Aim**

1) grab the topic for each lecture ( ie all text before word Lecture ) from **grab.txt** and paste that for each corresponding lectures in **main.txt** ( after giving a space to the hyphen)

2) Add suffix .mp4 for each lecture/line in main.txt

**Expected output**

```
X9tTDHSc-32313922.mp4-X9tTDHSc-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 1 - Definition.mp4
6auM6kSh-32313922.mp4-6auM6kSh-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 2 - Objectives of Auditing.mp4
F3LUhgbw-32313922.mp4-F3LUhgbw-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 3 - Scope of Auditing.mp4
F3LUhvvv-32313999.mp4-F3LUhvvv-32313999.mp4.mp4 Lecture 19 - Just a test for it to work randomly.mp4
NTyKAqNx-32313922.mp4-NTyKAqNx-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 4 - Types of Audit.mp4
RJUSaTnb-32313922.mp4-RJUSaTnb-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 5 - Inherent Limitations.mp4
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: Does `grab.txt` contain the word "Lecture" on every line (the random example you added doesn't have it)? Will the lectures in `grab.txt` always be in the same order as the ones in  `main.txt`? Will every record in `main.txt` have a matching record in `grab.txt` (and vice versa)?

Comment: @DaveCross yes the word lecture will be there on every line , sorry it was a typo , yes their order will be same always , yes it will have a matching record always

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                       # process file 1
    for(i=1;i<=NF-2;i++)        # dont store last two fields
        a[$NF]=a[$NF] OFS $i    # hash indexing on the number in the end
    next
}
($(NF-1) in a) {                # if the number found in hash
    print $0 a[$(NF-1)] ".mp4"  # output
}' grab main                    # mind the file order
```

Output:

```
X9tTDHSc-32313922.mp4-X9tTDHSc-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 1 - Definition.mp4
6auM6kSh-32313922.mp4-6auM6kSh-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 2 - Objectives of Auditing.mp4
F3LUhgbw-32313922.mp4-F3LUhgbw-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 3 - Scope of Auditing.mp4
NTyKAqNx-32313922.mp4-NTyKAqNx-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 4 - Types of Audit.mp4
RJUSaTnb-32313922.mp4-RJUSaTnb-32313922.mp4.mp4 Lecture 5 -  Inherent Limitations.mp4
F3LUhvvv-32313999.mp4-F3LUhvvv-32313999.mp4.mp4 Lecture 19 - Just a test for it to work.mp4
```

Notice that the `for()` will flatten extra space between words in the `grab` file to a single space.

Answer (score 4):

In perl:

```
open(my $mainfh, "main.txt");
open(my $grabfh, "grab.txt");
while(<$mainfh>) { #loop through all lines in main.txt
    chomp; #remove the newline
    $_ .= " " . <$grabfh>; # add a space and the following line from grab.txt
    s/ Lecture \d+$/.mp4/; #change the ending " Lecture SOMENUMBER " by ".mp4"
    print $_;
}
```

This gives the output you requested. But the output you want is rather strange...

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following without hard coding field numbers tested and written with shown samples written in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/Lecture [0-9]+/){
  var=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
FNR==NR{
  a[var]=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
  next
}
(var in a){
  print $0,a[var]".mp4"
}
' grab.txt main.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/Lecture [0-9]+/){        ##Using match function which will match regex Lecture space and digits in current line in both Input_files.
  var=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##storing sub string in current line which has matched regex value part fro current line.
}
FNR==NR{                           ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when first Input_file is being read.
  a[var]=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)     ##Creating array a with index var and having sub string till 1 character before matched regex in current line.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(var in a){                        ##Checking if var is present in array a then do following.
  print $0,a[var]".mp4"            ##Printing current line with value of index var and .mp4 string here.
}
' grab.txt main.txt                ##Mentioning grab and main files here to program.
```

Comment: yes i tested it , it works perfectly